# pass value from view form to partial view rendered in a modal

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I got a question on passing an id from a form to a partial view in a modal.

So this is my view where the form is and the button that calls an ajax modal:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectId)
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="launch" value= @item.Id role="button">do it</button>
}
```

This is my ajax call that comes from the class "launch" in the button on the view:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#triage-modal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 700,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("defectsPartial")");
            },
                buttons:{
                    "Close": function(){
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
        });
        $(".launch").click(function () {
            $("#triage-modal").dialog("open");
        })
    });
</script>
```

And this is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult defectsPartial()
{
    return PartialView("defectsPartial");
}
```

So my question is how can I get the `@item.Id` value from the view form, through the modal and to the partial view?  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: pass the id in action paremeter and get it in view

Comment: @EhsanSajjad if I put int id in the action parameter I get a null value error.

Comment: you have to pass from the load function as well

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Like this load for the Url.Action?  How can I find out how to do that?

Comment: I did this $(this).load("@Url.Action("defectsPartial", new { id = 1 })");..... and it passed 1 to the controller parameter :).  Any idea how I can replace 1 with the button value?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

`<script>
    var theId = -1;
    $(function () {
        $("#triage-modal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 700,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("defectsPartial")?id=" + theId);
            },
                buttons:{
                    "Close": function(){
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
        });
        $(".launch").click(function () {
            $("#triage-modal").dialog("open");
            theId = $(this).attr("value");
        })
    });
</script>`

It is a bit strange since you are using the open function of the modal to do the load so you need to store the Id somewhere are refer to it from here, consider doing the load in the click event of the launch button instead, then you can use the Id directly